# Reading String from File with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file, string

This one is weird. Hopefully I will ask the right question:

I'm using an md5 method to create a checksum value which I then write to a file. Then afterwards I read the file using this:

```
NSString * id_From_File = [[NSString alloc]
                                  initWithContentsOfFile:path_to_ID
                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                  error:&error];
```

The result gets placed in a NSString which when I print gives me very strange behaviour. For example when I use this to print,

```
id_with_date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"  %@  %@", dateString, id_From_File];
```

it will print both strings if dateString is placed in the first parameter and id_From_File in the second. If I switch them around (which I need to do) only id_From_File shows.

Edit 1: Example of the switch:

```
id_with_date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@  %@", id_From_File, dateString];
```

I strongly believe this has something to do with the encoding of the id_From_File string.

Any knowledge!?

Thanks,

Comment: that shouldn't have. Can you post the code when you switch them

Comment: Do you mean when I switch the order of the parameters? Check Edit 1 above.

Comment: As described, the behavior doesn't make any sense.  I'd suggest creating a small test project that shows the problem that people can download.  That will either help someone find the problem, or you'll discover it yourself in the process of creating it.

Comment: I figured it out! check out my answer if you like.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NSString should actually be capable of recognizing null characters as the file ending. Did you try to use a different method to load the string. I'd go for this one instead:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

This method automatically detects the file's encoding instead of decoding it with a fixed one.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem!

It has to do with the fact that some strings use a null character to identify the end. Allow me to explain:

Lets say you have two strings, one with a null character at the end and one that doesn't. Depending on which way you order them, they will be read differently when concatenated.

```
 "somestring(null char)" + "another string"
```

The above, in some code, will read

```
 somestring
```

if places are switched

```
 "another string" + "somestring(null char)"
```

then you get

```
"another string somestring"
```

My simple hack to fix this was to make a new string with a substring of "some string" which easily got rid of that last char that was causing the bug.

I hope this is clear and helpful!

Comment: I hope you're using `+` as shorthand and not saying that you've been performing your Objective-C string concatenation with it? Because that won't do string concatenation, it'll do pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Eric Brotto: The real question is why you're writing a null character into the file in the first place.